# Error in tcltk::as.tclObj(X) : cannot handle object of mode 'list

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, sqldf

I'm very new to R studio and `Sqldf`. I don't know what the issue is even if I wanted to thoroughly explain it. I am trying to use a SQL code to count up all distinct zip codes in the column `zip_code`. I know I need `Distinct` and `Count` somewhere but I don't know how it works with `Sqldf`. I also don't know why I am getting the following error when doing this basic code:

```r
Det_Crime %>% sqldf("select zip_code, from Det_Crime")
```

**Error in tcltk::as.tclObj(X) : cannot handle object of mode 'list**

My data:

[image]

Also is there a way to do this on `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

langtang's dplyr method is good. As to your error and SQL issues:

- One doesn't pass a frame to `sqldf`, one should only pass the query. In this case, try `sqldf(mtcars, "select cyl")` and see the error. This is because `sqldf` is trying to do something string-like to the first argument which is not a string. It will look for specific frames based on the tables reference in the SQL query itself, so `from Det_Crime` will trigger it to look for the object `Det_Crime` in the calling environment (or higher).

  Resolution: do not use `sqldf(.)` in a `%>%`-pipe as you've done. (It may *precede* a pipe if desired.)
- `select zip_code, from Det_Crime` is invalid SQL, the comma is wrong.

  Resolution: just `sqldf("select zip_code from Det_Crime")` is a start.

Ultimately, you can get what you need in SQL with

```r
sqldf("select zip_code, count(*) as n from Det_Crime group by zip_code")
```

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
Det_Crime <- tibble(zip_code=c("01001", "01001", "01002"))
```

Use `dplyr::count()`

```
Det_Crime %>% count(zip_code)
```

Output:

```
  zip_code     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 01001        2
2 01002        1
```

Answer (score 1):

sqldf is used in a pipline like this.  We use the builtin BOD data frame as an example.  The brace brackets prevent it from automatically inserting the left side into the first argument of sqldf and [.] in the SQL string refers to the left hand side of the pipe.

```
BOD %>% { sqldf("select * from [.]") }
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 2    2   10.3
## 3    3   19.0
## 4    4   16.0
## 5    5   15.6
## 6    7   19.8
```

Alternately use it standalone without the pipe.  This gives the same result.

```
sqldf("select * from BOD")
```

Regarding how to compute the number of distinct values in a column this gives the number of distinct values in the cyl column of the built-in mtcars data frame. Replace count(...) with count(*) if you want the number of rows instead.

```
sqldf("select count(distinct cyl) as count from mtcars")
##   count
## 1     3
```

To get the number of rows for each cyl:

```
sqldf("select cyl, count(*) as count
       from mtcars
       group by cyl")
##   cyl count
## 1   4    11
## 2   6     7
## 3   8    14
```

Comment: What's the syntax for the neo-base `|>` (forward pipe)?

Comment: IT's a bit awkward with |> but this works: `BOD |> list() |> setNames(".") |> with(sqldf("select * from [.]"))`

Comment: So you stick it into a list as its only element and rename that element `.` Maybe you need a helper infix operator named `|.>`? Or perhaps a prefix function named `l.`

Comment: If the purpose is to only use base R it's probably easier to use the Bizarro pipe which isn't really a pipe but looks like one.  `BOD ->.; sqldf("select * from [.]")`

Comment: Kewl. Looking at your comment and that construction I initially thought it was a three character operator, but then realized you were just leaving out the space and were really just creating a temporary variable named `"dot"` or `"punkt"`.